# Error when trying install dependencies in a project

Tags: node.js, npm

I 've  installing a simple project in node and angular to learning some about jasmin tests. So in the beginner of the download and install configuration I 've deal with this problems when I make npm install:

```
node-pre-gyp install --fallback-to-build

node-pre-gyp WARN Using request for node-pre-gyp https download
node-pre-gyp WARN Pre-built binaries not installable for sqlite3@4.2.0 and node@12.16.1 (node-v72 ABI, unknown) (falling back to source compile with node-gyp)
node-pre-gyp WARN Hit error self signed certificate in certificate chain
gyp WARN install got an error, rolling back install
gyp ERR! configure error
gyp ERR! stack Error: self signed certificate in certificate chain
gyp ERR! stack     at TLSSocket.onConnectSecure (_tls_wrap.js:1473:34)
gyp ERR! stack     at TLSSocket.emit (events.js:311:20)
gyp ERR! stack     at TLSSocket._finishInit (_tls_wrap.js:916:8)
gyp ERR! stack     at TLSWrap.ssl.onhandshakedone (_tls_wrap.js:686:12)
gyp ERR! System Windows_NT 10.0.16299
gyp ERR! command "C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node.exe" "C:\\Users\\s018150\\AppData\\Roaming\\npm\\node_modules\\node-gyp\\bin\\node-gyp.js" "configure" "--fallback-to-build" "--module=D:\\Alura\\alura_testes_angular\\api\\node_modules\\sqlite3\\lib\\binding\\node-v72-win32-x64\\node_sqlite3.node" "--module_name=node_sqlite3" "--module_path=D:\\Alura\\alura_testes_angular\\api\\node_modules\\sqlite3\\lib\\binding\\node-v72-win32-x64" "--napi_version=5" "--node_abi_napi=napi" "--napi_build_version=0" "--node_napi_label=node-v72" "--python=C:\\Python27\\pythonw.exe"
gyp ERR! cwd D:\Alura\alura_testes_angular\api\node_modules\sqlite3
gyp ERR! node -v v12.16.1
gyp ERR! node-gyp -v v7.0.0
gyp ERR! not ok
node-pre-gyp ERR! build error
node-pre-gyp ERR! stack Error: Failed to execute 'C:\Program Files\nodejs\node.exe C:\Users\s018150\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\node-gyp\bin\node-gyp.js configure --fallback-to-build --module=D:\Alura\alura_testes_angular\api\node_modules\sqlite3\lib\binding\node-v72-win32-x64\node_sqlite3.node --module_name=node_sqlite3 --module_path=D:\Alura\alura_testes_angular\api\node_modules\sqlite3\lib\binding\node-v72-win32-x64 --napi_version=5 --node_abi_napi=napi --napi_build_version=0 --node_napi_label=node-v72 --python=C:\Python27\pythonw.exe' (1)
node-pre-gyp ERR! stack     at ChildProcess.<anonymous> (D:\Alura\alura_testes_angular\api\node_modules\sqlite3\node_modules\node-pre-gyp\lib\util\compile.js:83:29)
node-pre-gyp ERR! stack     at ChildProcess.emit (events.js:311:20)
node-pre-gyp ERR! stack     at maybeClose (internal/child_process.js:1021:16)
node-pre-gyp ERR! stack     at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (internal/child_process.js:286:5)
node-pre-gyp ERR! System Windows_NT 10.0.16299
node-pre-gyp ERR! command "C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node.exe" "D:\\Alura\\alura_testes_angular\\api\\node_modules\\sqlite3\\node_modules\\node-pre-gyp\\bin\\node-pre-gyp" "install" "--fallback-to-build"
node-pre-gyp ERR! cwd D:\Alura\alura_testes_angular\api\node_modules\sqlite3
node-pre-gyp ERR! node -v v12.16.1
node-pre-gyp ERR! node-pre-gyp -v v0.11.0
node-pre-gyp ERR! not ok
Failed to execute 'C:\Program Files\nodejs\node.exe C:\Users\s018150\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\node-gyp\bin\node-gyp.js configure --fallback-to-build --module=D:\Alura\alura_testes_angular\api\node_modules\sqlite3\lib\binding\node-v72-win32-x64\node_sqlite3.node --module_name=node_sqlite3 --module_path=D:\Alura\alura_testes_angular\api\node_modules\sqlite3\lib\binding\node-v72-win32-x64 --napi_version=5 --node_abi_napi=napi --napi_build_version=0 --node_napi_label=node-v72 --python=C:\Python27\pythonw.exe' (1)
npm WARN alurapic@1.0.0 No description
npm WARN alurapic@1.0.0 No repository field.

npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
npm ERR! errno 1
npm ERR! sqlite3@4.2.0 install: `node-pre-gyp install --fallback-to-build`
npm ERR! Exit status 1
npm ERR!
npm ERR! Failed at the sqlite3@4.2.0 install script.
npm ERR! This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in: node-pre-gyp install --fallback-to-build

node-pre-gyp WARN Using request for node-pre-gyp https download
node-pre-gyp WARN Pre-built binaries not installable for sqlite3@4.2.0 and node@12.16.1 (node-v72 ABI, unknown) (falling back to source compile with node-gyp)
node-pre-gyp WARN Hit error self signed certificate in certificate chain
gyp WARN install got an error, rolling back install
gyp ERR! configure error
gyp ERR! stack Error: self signed certificate in certificate chain
gyp ERR! stack     at TLSSocket.onConnectSecure (_tls_wrap.js:1473:34)
gyp ERR! stack     at TLSSocket.emit (events.js:311:20)
gyp ERR! stack     at TLSSocket._finishInit (_tls_wrap.js:916:8)
gyp ERR! stack     at TLSWrap.ssl.onhandshakedone (_tls_wrap.js:686:12)
gyp ERR! System Windows_NT 10.0.16299
gyp ERR! command "C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node.exe" "C:\\Users\\s018150\\AppData\\Roaming\\npm\\node_modules\\node-gyp\\bin\\node-gyp.js" "configure" "--fallback-to-build" "--module=D:\\Alura\\alura_testes_angular\\api\\node_modules\\sqlite3\\lib\\binding\\node-v72-win32-x64\\node_sqlite3.node" "--module_name=node_sqlite3" "--module_path=D:\\Alura\\alura_testes_angular\\api\\node_modules\\sqlite3\\lib\\binding\\node-v72-win32-x64" "--napi_version=5" "--node_abi_napi=napi" "--napi_build_version=0" "--node_napi_label=node-v72" "--python=C:\\Python27\\pythonw.exe"
gyp ERR! cwd D:\Alura\alura_testes_angular\api\node_modules\sqlite3
gyp ERR! node -v v12.16.1
gyp ERR! node-gyp -v v7.0.0
gyp ERR! not ok
node-pre-gyp ERR! build error
node-pre-gyp ERR! stack Error: Failed to execute 'C:\Program Files\nodejs\node.exe C:\Users\s018150\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\node-gyp\bin\node-gyp.js configure --fallback-to-build --module=D:\Alura\alura_testes_angular\api\node_modules\sqlite3\lib\binding\node-v72-win32-x64\node_sqlite3.node --module_name=node_sqlite3 --module_path=D:\Alura\alura_testes_angular\api\node_modules\sqlite3\lib\binding\node-v72-win32-x64 --napi_version=5 --node_abi_napi=napi --napi_build_version=0 --node_napi_label=node-v72 --python=C:\Python27\pythonw.exe' (1)
node-pre-gyp ERR! stack     at ChildProcess.<anonymous> (D:\Alura\alura_testes_angular\api\node_modules\sqlite3\node_modules\node-pre-gyp\lib\util\compile.js:83:29)
node-pre-gyp ERR! stack     at ChildProcess.emit (events.js:311:20)
node-pre-gyp ERR! stack     at maybeClose (internal/child_process.js:1021:16)
node-pre-gyp ERR! stack     at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (internal/child_process.js:286:5)
node-pre-gyp ERR! System Windows_NT 10.0.16299
node-pre-gyp ERR! command "C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node.exe" "D:\\Alura\\alura_testes_angular\\api\\node_modules\\sqlite3\\node_modules\\node-pre-gyp\\bin\\node-pre-gyp" "install" "--fallback-to-build"
node-pre-gyp ERR! cwd D:\Alura\alura_testes_angular\api\node_modules\sqlite3
node-pre-gyp ERR! node -v v12.16.1
node-pre-gyp ERR! node-pre-gyp -v v0.11.0
node-pre-gyp ERR! not ok
Failed to execute 'C:\Program Files\nodejs\node.exe C:\Users\s018150\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\node-gyp\bin\node-gyp.js configure --fallback-to-build --module=D:\Alura\alura_testes_angular\api\node_modules\sqlite3\lib\binding\node-v72-win32-x64\node_sqlite3.node --module_name=node_sqlite3 --module_path=D:\Alura\alura_testes_angular\api\node_modules\sqlite3\lib\binding\node-v72-win32-x64 --napi_version=5 --node_abi_napi=napi --napi_build_version=0 --node_napi_label=node-v72 --python=C:\Python27\pythonw.exe' (1)
npm WARN alurapic@1.0.0 No description
npm WARN alurapic@1.0.0 No repository field.

npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
npm ERR! errno 1
npm ERR! sqlite3@4.2.0 install: `node-pre-gyp install --fallback-to-build`
npm ERR! Exit status 1
npm ERR!
npm ERR! Failed at the sqlite3@4.2.0 install script.
npm ERR! This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
```

I've tried some commands like `npm install sqlite3` or  `npm install sqlite3 --fallback-to-build`. And too I had updtate the npm version and removed the node_modules directory and installed all again but the same error messages occurred.

My package.json file is :

```
{
  "name": "alurapic",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "",
  "main": "server.js",
  "scripts": {
    "test": "echo \"Error: no test specified\" && exit 1",
    "start": "node server.js"
  },
  "author": "",
  "license": "ISC",
  "dependencies": {
    "body-parser": "^1.18.2",
    "cors": "^2.8.4",
    "cryptiles": ">=4.1.2",
    "express": "^4.16.3",
    "jimp": "^0.2.28",
    "jsonwebtoken": "^8.2.0",
    "multer": "^1.3.0",
    "node-pre-gyp": "^0.15.0",
    "sqlite3": "^4.1.0",
    "uuid": "^3.2.1"
  }
}
```

}

Answer (score 3):

Could you try following command?

```
NODE_TLS_REJECT_UNAUTHORIZED=0 npm install
```

or, if under windows, two commands

```
set NODE_TLS_REJECT_UNAUTHORIZED=0
npm install
```

Answer (score 2):

I was with this same issue.

Solved and worked for me:

1. Define python in enviromnents variables.
2. Erase node_modules and package-lock.json
3. `npm i sqlite3@5.0.0`
4. `npm i`
5. `npm start`

I'm using v14.13.0 version of node

**My ambient**

*Angular CLI: 10.1.3
Node: 14.13.0
OS: win32 x64*

*Angular:

Ivy Workspace:
Package                      Version

@angular-devkit/architect    0.1001.3 (cli-only)

@angular-devkit/core         10.1.3 (cli-only)

@angular-devkit/schematics   10.1.3 (cli-only)

@schematics/angular          10.1.3 (cli-only)

@schematics/update           0.1001.3 (cli-only)*